# Probability of getting 7 numbers smaller or equal to 59, from a draw of 20 numbers out of 80

Tags: probability, lotteries

What is the Probability of getting $7$ numbers smaller or equal to $59$, from a draw of $20$ numbers out of $80$?

I can work out the probability of getting them in the 1st $7$ numbers

$$59/80 * 58/79 * ... * 53/74 = 0,107390589$$

However, I see there are many other possibilities. Getting $7$ numbers under $59$ from the first $8$ numbers, from the first $9$ numbers, ... etc.

Should I calculate them one by one from $7$ to $20$ numbers, and them add them all?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get *exactly* $7$ numbers smaller or equal to $59$, or *at least* $7$ such numbers?

Comment: Hi @BarryCipra, thanks for your question. It'd be _AT LEAST_ 7 numbers smaller or equal to 59 within those 20 numbers that are drawn out of 80 numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the wording, English is not my first language. Let me know if it's clear now

Comment: If it is exactly 7 numbers: you have to **choose** $7$ numbers from $1$ to $59$ ($59$ numbers) and **choose** $13$ numbers from $60$ to $80$ ($80-60+1$ numbers).

Comment: @BarryCipra, sorry, it'd be at least 7 numbers smaller or equal to 59. I misunderstood the question

Comment: @PedroGonzalezRuiz Please update your post informing us it is about choosing **at least** 7 numbers. I was about to post a wrong answer because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting $n$ numbers smaller or equal to $59$ by choosing $20$ numbers from $\{1,2,3,...,80\}$ is like the probability of choosing $n$ numbers from $\{1,2,3,...,59\}$, and the rest of them ($20-n$ numbers) from $\{60,61,...,80\}$ with all legible values of $n$, thus:

$\displaystyle p_n=\dfrac{{59 \choose n}{80-59 \choose 20-n}}{{80 \choose 20}}=\dfrac{{59 \choose n}{21 \choose 20-n}}{{80 \choose 20}}$

As we want at least $7$ numbers less than or equal to $59$ we should say $7 \leq n \leq 20$. Hence, the probability will be:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=7}^{20} p_n=\sum_{n=7}^{20} \dfrac{{59 \choose n}{21 \choose 20-n}}{{80 \choose 20}}$

Comment: The upper limit of your sums should be $20$ because that is how many numbers you draw.

Comment: @RossMillikan Very important note. Thank you, Ross.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a stupid method but i think its easy to understand why it works just by looking at it:

let $a = \frac{59*58*...*53}{80*79*...*74}$
then
$$a + \sum^{x = 12}_{x=1}{\Big(aC_{x}^{7+x}\prod^{n=x}_{n=1}{\frac{22-n}{74-n}}\Big)}$$